# LNK2001 with a vector function

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am using C++ MVS2019 and trying to use a vector function declared in h. file and defined in a secondary .cpp file, but the code doesn't compile and throws me 2 errors:

```
1. Error    LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  library D:\VS_cpp\library\library\x64\Release\library.exe   1   
2. Error    LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "struct Vector<int> __cdecl Biblio::debtors(void)" (?debtors@Biblio@@YA?AU?$Vector@H@@XZ)    library D:\VS_cpp\library\library\library\library.obj   1
```

At the same time if I use the same code in Code Blocks it compiles perfectly.
MAIN.cpp:

```
#include "test_int.h"
using namespace Biblio;
int main()
{
    vector<int> debtorss = debtors();
    int test = test_int();
}
```

test_int.h:

```
#ifndef BIBLIO_H_INCLUDED
#define BIBLIO_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

namespace Biblio
{
    vector<int> debtors();
    int test_int();
}

#endif
```

test_int.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

namespace Biblio
{
    vector<int> debtors()
    {
        vector<int> abc{ 1,2,3 };
        return abc;
    }

    int test_int()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If I kill "debtors()" function in all files and compile just with "int test_int()" function - everything is fine. But any vector function causes the same error. Since it works in CodeBlocks it might be some Visual Studio settings that have to be changed but since I am just studying I don't know much.

Would be happy to get any advice. Thanks.

Comment: unrelated but you should avoid `using namespace std` in general and never use it in a header file

Comment: `test_int.cpp` should have `#include test_int.h`

Comment: Nothing to do with the vector, you need to link `test_int.obj` with your code, that's all.

Comment: please also provide a [mre], your error message has `Vector` with a capital `V` which doesn't match your code

Comment: My guess is the file `test_int.cpp` is not part of your project in Visual Studio 2019. Being in the same folder does not matter. It needs to be part of the project.